# Magento: Wrong price when adding configurable product to cart

Tags: magento, product, configurable

we’ve been trying to solve this problem without any success so far.

We have configurable products by size, and as they get bigger, they get more expensive. The problem is that no matter what size the customer chooses, when he adds it to the cart, the price on cart is for the smallest size, showing a wrong price.

The funny thing is that with the default theme, prices are shown correctly at cart, but when we load the custom theme we use (it’s called ‘blanco’’), the problem begins.

Please help, it's driving me crazy and I searched for help everywhere. Thank you,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

The templates of your theme are obviously buggy and do not query the product price correctly. You should compare all templates in `app/design/frontend/default/blanco` with their counterparts in `app/design/frontend/base/default`, especially `checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`, if your theme overrides that one.